# How to optimize multiple jQuery events?

Tags: jquery, events, fadeout

How can I make it more easier?

> `$("#one").click(function() {    $("#container").fadeOut(200);   });`
>   `$("#two").click(function() {    $("#container").fadeOut(200);   });`
>   `$("#three").click(function() {  $("#container").fadeOut(200);   });`
>   `$("#four").click(function() {   $("#container").fadeOut(200);   });`

Comment: add a common class to each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either add class to each element .class

```
$('.class').click(function () {
    $("#container").fadeOut(200);
});
```

or combine the ids to the selector

```
$('#one,#two,#three,#four').click(function () {
    $("#container").fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: +1 - Didn't see your answer. Otherwise wouldn't have posted a duplicate!